# Why does gpg's secret and public key have the same keyid?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption

On my Windows machine running Cygwin, When I run

```
gpg --list-keys --keyid-format LONG
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

Both the pub and sec keys have the same value. sub and ssb have the same value. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I'm not a GPG expert, but since it uses public key crypto,  which generates public-private key pairs as a matched set, it makes sense for the pair to share the same ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. this is expected behavior.

A Key ID (actually a shortened version of the key Fingerprint) is calculated using only Public Key material and so can ONLY refer to the Public Key.

Secret Keys do not have a separate "Key ID", gpg is just showing the "Public Key ID" that the Secret Key is paired to.

It may seem like it could be confusing. For example: if you import a Secret Key, how will gpg know which Public Key it is paired with? But this is not a problem because whenever you export a Secret Key, the exported (and subsequently imported) "Secret Key Packet" will always contain the Public Key as well.